# Export SVG out of matplotlib-venn

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib-venn

I have started to use matplotlib-venn for plotting venn diagram. It's a very useful tool, but I would like to know whether the graph generated can be saved in an SVG (or even pdf) format. I want to keep the graph vector, not rasterize it as in png.

I think there is a way, so if you can point me to it, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the standard `savefig` method. Just give your output path a '.svg' extension:

```
from matplotlib_venn import venn2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

venn2(subsets = (3, 2, 1))
plt.savefig('venn2.svg')
```

You can save to PNG with a `.png` extension and... you can probably see where this is going for other formats.

Comment: Thanks... Will try!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to configure the SVG 'backend':

> The matplotlib frontend or matplotlib API is the set of classes that
>   do the heavy lifting, creating and managing figures, text, lines,
>   plots and so on (Artist tutorial). This is an abstract interface that
>   knows nothing about output. The backends are device-dependent drawing
>   devices, aka renderers, that transform the frontend representation to
>   hardcopy or a display device (What is a backend?). Example backends:
>   PS creates PostScript® hardcopy, SVG creates Scalable Vector Graphics
>   hardcopy,...

```
> # The default backend; one of GTK GTKAgg GTKCairo GTK3Agg GTK3Cairo
> # CocoaAgg MacOSX Qt4Agg Qt5Agg TkAgg WX WXAgg Agg Cairo GDK PS PDF SVG
> # Template.
> # You can also deploy your own backend outside of matplotlib by
> # referring to the module name (which must be in the PYTHONPATH) as
> # 'module://my_backend'. backend : qt4agg
```

Src: http://matplotlib.org/Matplotlib.pdf